# imfile in rsyslog in AIX servers

Tags: linux, unix, aix

AIX server's rsyslog (imfile module) is not forwarding custom application logs from a specific folder that has multiple log files generated each and every day. The log file's name pattern differs. I need help forwarding logs from those files and the files that will be generated in future. As of now in the configuration, i have given the wildcard (in $InputFileName) to read the files as "*.log.*" as per the file name's pattern.

The file names are as follows:

```
abcd0000.log.190610
sdef0001.log.190611
asdfghjklas0000.log.190612
qwerty0004.log.190613
```

The imfile module configuration part is as follows:

```
$ModLoad imfile
$InputFileName /usr/bada/custom/application/*.log.*
$InputFileTag application1:
$InputFileSeverity info
$InputFileFacility local6
$InputFileMonitor
```

The version of rsyslog is:

```
rsyslogd 8.4.2, compiled with:
FEATURE_REGEXP:                          yes
GSSAPI kerberos 5 support:               No
FEATURE_DEBUG (debug build, slow code):  No
32bit Atomic operations supported:       Yes
64bit Atomic operations supported:       No
memory allocator:                        system default
Runtime Instrumentation (slow code):     No
uuid support:                            No
Number of Bits in RainerScript integers: 64
```

This rsyslog is running on the Operating system,

```
AIX 7.2
7200-02-02-1806
```

Comment: This appears to be a repeated question to https://superuser.com/q/1448624/513541, which has an answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Imfile in rsyslog running on AIX Server 7.2](https://superuser.com/questions/1448624/imfile-in-rsyslog-running-on-aix-server-7-2)