# Imfile in rsyslog running on AIX Server 7.2

Tags: linux, unix, aix

AIX server's rsyslog (imfile module) is not forwarding custom application logs from a specific folder that has multiple log files generated each and every day. The log file's name pattern differs. I need help forwarding logs from those files and the files that will be generated in future. As of now in the configuration, i have given the wildcard (in `$InputFileName`) to read the files as `.log.` as per the file name's pattern.

The file names are as follows:

```
abcd0000.log.190610
sdef0001.log.190611
asdfghjklas0000.log.190612
qwerty0004.log.190613
```

The imfile module configuration part is as follows:

```
$ModLoad imfile
$InputFileName /usr/bada/custom/application/*.log.*
$InputFileTag application1:
$InputFileSeverity info
$InputFileFacility local6
$InputFileMonitor
```

The version of rsyslog is:

```
rsyslogd 8.4.2, compiled with:
FEATURE_REGEXP:                          yes
GSSAPI kerberos 5 support:               No
FEATURE_DEBUG (debug build, slow code):  No
32bit Atomic operations supported:       Yes
64bit Atomic operations supported:       No
memory allocator:                        system default
Runtime Instrumentation (slow code):     No
uuid support:                            No
Number of Bits in RainerScript integers: 64
```

This rsyslog is running on the Operating system,

```
AIX 7.2
7200-02-02-1806
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but I believe the issue is that you are using the legacy $ModLoad syntax which I think doesn't like wildcards in the file name.

Try switching to "module(load="imfile")" and using the updated syntax like

```
input(type="imfile"
      File="/usr/bada/custom/applicaiton/*.log.*"
      Tag="application1:"
      Severity="info"
      Facility="local6")
```

Also found this info on wildcards from https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/imfile.html#wildcards

Before Version: 8.25.0

Wildcards are only supported in the filename part, not in directory names.

/var/log/*.log  works.

/var/log/*/syslog.log does not work.

Since Version: 8.25.0

Wildcards are supported in filename and paths which means these samples will work:

/var/log/*.log works. *

/var/log/*/syslog.log works. *

/var/log/*/*.log works. *

All matching files in all matching subfolders will work. Note that this may decrease performance in imfile depending on how many directories and files are being watched dynamically.